# List<T> adding issue

Tags: c#, list

Basically I have two classes, for example Class A and Class B

Class A contains a list, List A

Class B contains a list, List B

Whenever I open a file, I use class B and it populates List B. Now to edit this file I have to populate List A, I normally create an object of Class B inside Class A.

i.e.

```
B file = new B; //creates an object of B
A = file; // assign B to A so all contents of B will populate A
```

The problem I am having is whenever I add an item to List A, it automatically updates List B in Class B. I have set List B like this:

```cs
List<typeofList> B {get; private set;}

//a default constructor
public B()
{
    B = new List<typeofList>();
}

// a constructor used to set updated list
public B(List<typeofList> thisCurrentList)
{
    B = thisCurrentList;
}

public addItemsToListB()
{
    //codes for adding
    //popoulates List B
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to add an item in List A and update List B in Class B ONLY if I call a method that does the adding in Class A.

But whenever I do:

```
A.Add(item); // this adds item to List A BUT also adds an item automatically in List    B(in Class B).
```

Any idea why is this happening? I debug the code but i have no idea whats going on in the line above.

Comment: `A = file` is a _reference_ to file, not a copy.  Read:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Maybe `listA` and `listB` are referencing the same object.

Comment: This is a confusingly-worded question in that sometimes you seem to be talking about A and B as if they *were* the list, and sometimes as if they're objects *containing* the list. Ignoring normal .NET naming conventions doesn't help, nor does the omission of the class declarations. A short but *complete* example using sensible names would make it much easier to answer clearly. (The actual issue is fairly obvious, but it's hard to write about it clearly when the question is termed in a confusing way.)

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> B file = new B; //creates an object of B
>
> A = file; // assign B to A so all contents of B will populate A

This is incorrect.  You are apparently expecting a copy of `file`, but you're really getting a reference to it.

That means changes to `A` necessarily mean changes to `B`.

If you want a copy, you need a constructor that does:

```
A = new B(file);
```

...and that constructor should make a fresh `B` that contains whatever `file` contained.  That way, changes to one do not affect the other.  Then, you can call your method on whichever object you choose.

Answer (score -1):

Simply doing the = operator with lists will make them associate with each other, so their internal data is shared.

If you want to copy, try this:

```
A = new List<typeOfList>(B)
```